# Froala not working properly in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, froala

I tried to integrate froala in Django as shown in [here](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/django)

It worked perfectly in forms but when the content rendered in DetailView it shows this. Is their any workaround.

Page as rendered by DetailView:

[image: Image as rendered by DetailView]

and in the froala image upload not working as shown in image:

[image: Image with error]

Comment: What if you add `mark_save` as a template filter?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem => `mark_safe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your image shows raw HTML, you should use `safe`:

```
{{ my_html|safe }}
```

It will prevent Django to escape your data.

Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe).